# How do I create an object in a JTabbedPane that accesses a class outside of the JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, class, object, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm creating a text based city management game and using JTabbedPanes inside a JFrame. The JTabbedPane has 4 main JPanels inside it to display (1)city population, (2) economic class breakdown,   (3) social class breakdown, and (4) overall approval rating. These JPanels have many other JPanels inside them to display content.

I will have approval rating calculated in the class "ApprovalRating" but for the moment used 46 as a place holder:

```
public class ApprovalRating {

  ApprovalRating(){
    int rating;
  }

  public void getRating() {
    int rating = 46;
  }
```

However I cannot seem to create an object that will be able to access the class or methods I need:

```
StaticsticsTab(){


avgApprove = new JPanel();
        ApprovalRating() t1 = new ApprovalRating();// this line doesn't work
        int myRating = t1.getRating();// t1 hasn't been created so this line won't work either
        JLabel rating = new JLabel(""+myRating);


}
```

(I've left out the majority of my StatisticsTab Class but I can post the whole thing if you feel like it would help. The rest is just creating JPanels and associated elements: JLabels etc.)

Here is my main method:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("City Manager");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.addTab("Statistics", new StatisticsTab());//Accesses JPanels made in this tab;

    frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
   frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Thanks so much to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

`ApprovalRating t1 = new ApprovalRating();` ... without the first `"()"`

`public void getRating()` doesn't return anything:

```
public class ApprovalRating {

  private int rating;

  public ApprovalRating() {
    // TODO implement rating calculation
    rating = 46; // int literal for now
  }

  public int getRating() {
    return rating;
  }
}
```